# get last post's link with SQL query

Tags: posts, query, mysql

I have installed a WP on website A and I want the last post's links in site B.
I haven't in site B any WP and I want to get the link of last post from website A.
so I can't use WP API like WP_Query and so on..

Is there possible I do this with remote connection to MuSql and get the last post link?

How do this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each site is WP, they'll both have RSS feeds. You're better off just to fetch the RSS feed and get the latest post link from that.

WP even has some built in support RSS parsing!

```
<?php
/**
 * An example of how to use fetch feed
 *
 * @uses    fetch_feed
 * @return  bool|string False on failure, the permalink on success
 */
function wpse60754_fetch_feed($feed_url)
{
    $feed = fetch_feed($feed_url);

    if(is_wp_error($feed))
        return false;

    $items = $feed->get_items(0, 1);

    if(count($items))
        return $items[0]->get_permalink();
    else
        return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you might be looking for.

http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/news/how-to-read-an-rss-feed-with-php-screencast/

Basically on the NON-WP site create a function that parses an RSS feed via `file_get_contents()` and `SimpleXmlElement()` combined to grab the titles.

Instead of a foreach loop though use do `$x[0]->whatever` like this:

```
<?php  

function getFeed($feed_url) {  

    $content = file_get_contents($feed_url);  
    $x = new SimpleXmlElement($content);  

    $entry = $x[0]->channel->item

    echo "<a href='$entry->link' title='$entry->title'>" . $entry->title . "</a>";  

}  
?>
```